# Schedule the sending of emails

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to use the Laravel 5 scheduler to have an application email send. I am using this code.

```
// app/Console/Kernal.php
$schedule->call(function()
{
    $newsletter = Newsletter::first()->toArray();

    Mail::send('emails.newsletter', $newsletter, function($message)
    {
        $message->to('example@test.com', 'John Doe')->subject('Test');
    });

})->cron('* * * * *');
```

And then I am manually calling it (for now) with `php artisan schedule:run` in the terminal. The terminal returns `Running scheduled command: Closure` and nothing else happens.

When I change the code to this, the first newsletter is being deleted. So it must be a problem with `Mail`. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
$schedule->call(function()
{
    $newsletter = Newsletter::first();

    $newsletter->delete();

})->cron('* * * * *');
```

Comment: Hard to say without some additional details. Does resources/views/emails/newsletter.blade.php exist? What do you see when you dump $message?

Comment: @Jason Yes, that view exists. The email sends fine when I put that code in any controller method as a test. But I am trying to make it send from the schedular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I think it was just a problem with my mail configuration. I switched to smtp and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever resolve this? I am having this exact problem now. The only way it says you can send an email is:

```
$schedule->command('foo')->sendOutputTo('path to file')->semailOutputTo('foo@example.com');
```

But there is no format or any additional message you can add from what i am seeing.

Comment: I think it was just a problem with my mail configuration. I switched to smtp and used [mailtrap](https://mailtrap.io) for testing. Everything seemed to work fine.